# how to show datetime from 2017-12-06 13:07:00+05:30 fromat to 2017-12-06 18:37:00 format in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timezone

I would like to convert timezone of datetime column in dataframe in python. This is how i did it.

```
df.dtypes
Out[11]: 
x1                 object
x2                 object
event_time datetime64[ns]
x3                float64
dtype: object

type(df.event_time)
Out[12]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

But the results look like this

```
df['event_time'].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Kolkata')
Out[2]: 
0       2017-12-06 13:07:00+05:30
1       2017-12-06 13:06:00+05:30
2       2017-12-06 13:05:00+05:30
3       2017-12-06 13:04:00+05:30
4       2017-12-06 13:03:00+05:30
5       2017-12-06 13:02:00+05:30
6       2017-12-06 13:01:00+05:30
7       2017-12-06 13:00:00+05:30
8       2017-12-06 12:59:00+05:30
9       2017-12-06 12:58:00+05:30
10      2017-12-06 12:57:00+05:30
11      2017-12-06 12:56:00+05:30
12      2017-12-06 12:55:00+05:30
```

Is there a way i can show datetime like below

```
 0       2017-12-06 18:37:00
 1       2017-12-06 18:36:00
```

Also, I am interested in changing the timezone by using `+05:30` instead of using the zone name `'Asia/Kolkata'`

```
EDIT : 


 df = pd.DataFrame({'event_time': [pd.Timestamp('2017-12-06 13:07:00'),pd.Timestamp('2017-12-06 13:06:00')]})

df['event_time'] = df['event_time'].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Kolkata')

print (df)
                 event_time
0 2017-12-06 13:07:00+05:30
1 2017-12-06 13:06:00+05:30

df['event_time'] = df['event_time'].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Kolkata').dt.tz_conver‌​t('UTC').dt.tz_local‌​ize(None) 
  File "<ipython-input-24-ee54cb3c6b25>", line 1
    df['event_time'] = df['event_time'].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Kolkata').dt.tz_conver‌​t('UTC').dt.tz_local‌​ize(None)
                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'event_time': [pd.Timestamp('2017-12-06 13:07:00'), 
                                     pd.Timestamp('2017-12-06 13:06:00')]})



df['event_time'] = df['event_time'].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Kolkata')
print (df)
                 event_time
0 2017-12-06 13:07:00+05:30
1 2017-12-06 13:06:00+05:30

df['event_time'] = df['event_time'].dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.tz_localize(None)
print (df)
           event_time
0 2017-12-06 07:37:00
1 2017-12-06 07:36:00
```

Comment: I add sample data, for me it working nice. `f['event_time'] = df['event_time'].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Kolkata')` does not work too?

Comment: `df['event_time'].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Kolkata')`  it works.. but i want output to be  like this  `2017-12-06 18:37:00` .. my output shows this `2017-12-06 13:07:00+05:30`  .. i want that +05:30 to be added... i tired the above code.. `df['event_time'].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Kolkata').dt.tz_localize(None)`  .. the result shows the same output `2017-12-06 13:07:00`

Comment: You forget convert to `UTC` ;)

Comment: df['event_time'].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Kolkata').dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.tz_localize(None)

Comment: This throws error : 
 `df['event_time'].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Kolkata').dt.tz_conver‌​t('UTC').dt.tz_local‌​ize(None) 
  File "<ipython-input-31-2db456cc7037>", line 1
    df['event_time'].dt.tz_localize('Asia/Kolkata').dt.tz_conver‌​t('UTC').dt.tz_local‌​ize(None)
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier`

Comment: It sometimes happens if copy comments, try copy answer.